# Fix iframe height to be exactly same as containing div

Tags: css, html, iframe

I have a simple 4-panel webpage set up mostly using divs and css. The panel divs are header, footer, menu, and content. The menu and content are supposed to be parallel columns with the same height.

Everything works fine until I put an iframe inside the content div. The content div then becomes taller than the menu div, even when I set them to the same height. I know that the iframe is the reason because this doesn't happen when I take out the iframe, but it's the content div - not the iframe - that actually is too tall.

How can I fix this? Some similar questions have been asked, but the proposed solutions didn't work for me, unless I was doing something wrong. Here's my complete code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<style>
    body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #header {
        background-color: #7D110C;
        height:100px;
    }
    #menu { 
        float:left;
        width:300px;
        background-color: lightGrey;
        min-height:500px; /* for modern browsers */
        height:auto !important; /* for modern browsers */
        height:500px; /* for IE5.x and IE6 */
    }
    #content { 
        margin-left:300px;
        background-color: white;
        min-height:500px; /* for modern browsers */
        height:auto !important; /* for modern browsers */
        height:500px; /* for IE5.x and IE6 */
    }
    #content iframe{
        width:100%;
        border:none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        background-color: pink;
        min-height:500px; /* for modern browsers */
        height:auto !important; /* for modern browsers */
        height:500px; /* for IE5.x and IE6 */
    }
    #footer { 
        clear:both;
        background-color: #7D110C;
        height:100px;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="menu"></div>
    <div id="content"><iframe id="content_iframe" name="content_iframe"></iframe></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log( $('#content').css('height') );
    console.log( $('#content_iframe').css('height') );
</script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`height:auto !important;` overrides `height:500px;` in `#content` and in `#content iframe`. If you get rid of the `height:auto !important;` in both CSS classes, it works fine. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TjgfM/)

Ok here's the real fix, just leave everything as is and add `display: block` to `#content iframe`. That fixes it. An iframe is an inline frame, hence the extra white space. [Updated jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TjgfM/1/)

Comment: However, why does attaching "height auto !important" to both #content and #content_iframe not give them both the same height?

Comment: Why add `height auto !important` in the first place!

Comment: To be honest I was just copying the format from a template I found somewhere and was loath to change it, but if I understand right, the function is to allow the menu & content divs to fill available space, making them taller than 500px if possible, but not shorter.

Comment: `height-auto` means that the div will just take the height of its contents.

Comment: Edited my answer with a real fix, the problem is that iframe is an inline element, that answers your question about both elements not having the same height.

Comment: This won't solve anything... If the iframe's height gets bigger or smaller than `500px`, the column will still get a different height from the menu: http://jsfiddle.net/TjgfM/2/

Comment: @m.spyratos It solves the problem of the `#content` div changing its height depending on it having an iframe inside it or not. @baixiwei seems content with setting a fixed height on the `#menu` and `#content` divs.

Comment: @user1846192 In the fiddle you provided, if you change the height of the iframe, the height of the `#content` changes too. If let's say the iframe height is `700px`, then `#content` will extend to `700px` too. If then you remove the iframe, `#content` height will drop. I am talking about your **real fix**, not the first one you provided.

Comment: In my case the iframe contains only internal data - sorry should have made this clear. user1846192's revised solution does what I think I want. Though I'm having trouble stating what that is precisely at a high level, at a more specific level I want the iframe to not result in adding superfluous whitespace, and adding display: block seems to accomplish that.

Comment: @user1846192 My apologies then :) You said "that answers your question about both elements not having the same height" and that confused me...

Comment: @m.spyratos No worries, I just re-read that comment and I can see where you're coming from :) I did mean the `#content` div and the `#content iframe` there.

Answer (score 1):

If you set a fixed `height:500px;` and the iframe is taller than this, you will get a scrollbar on the side.

If you want a fixed height at all times, remove both `height: auto !important` and `min-height: 500px` and leave only `height:500px`.

- `height-auto`: The browser calculates the height. This is default.
- `min-height`: Defines the minimum height

The following will make `menu` and `content` have the same height at all times.

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="menu"></div>
  <div id="content"><iframe id="content_iframe" name="content_iframe"></iframe></div>
</div>
```

**CSS** (Just add this to the already existent)

```
#wrapper { display: table; }
#menu { display: table-cell; } /* Remove the float */
#content { display: table-cell; } /* Remove the float */
```

Note, this won't work on IE7 and below though. Either you'll have to use fixed height for both `menu` and `content` or javascript.

Comment: Well, this does seem to make the menu and content divs the same height, but - they're not the height I set. In other words, instead of just the content div being taller than what I set, now both the menu and content divs are. How can I get them to obey my set height?

Comment: Remove the `height:auto;`. Why do you have it there. Also if you want a fixed `500px` height, remove `min-height:500px;` too. Leave **only** this: `height:500px;`

Comment: You have to decide what you want first. On another comment you say you just want a **minimum height**. Here you say you want a **fixed height** (that is the one you will set it to).

Comment: Sorry - what I want is a minimum height. I was imprecise here, apologies. The issue wasn't so much that they weren't obeying my set height as that I seemed to be getting added vertical space for no apparent reason, which I didn't want to happen. It wasn't filling the available space but adding a specific amount of extra height on top of the minimum I'd set. I think user1846192's revised answer explains where that space was coming from and how to get rid of it.

Answer (score 1):

For modern browsers you can try this:

add `position:relative` to `#content`

remove width, height, min-heigth from `#content iframe` and add this instead:

```
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
```

No idea what to do for IE 5 and 6, though.